# Understanding of bool filter

Tags: elasticsearch

According to elasticsearch doc at http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/combining-filters.html, a bool filter can be the following:

```
{
   "bool" : {
      "must" :     [
          A,
          B
       ],
      "should" :   [
          C,
          D
       ],
      "must_not" : [
          E,
          F
       ],
   }
}
```

In meaning, it is equivalent to the following logic operations:

```
A and B and (C or D) and (not E) and (not F)
```

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: That would be correct, yes.

Comment: Andrei, if you make your response an answer, I will select it. The reason I am asking this question is that "must_not"  can be confusing. It is not "not (E and F)" Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Andrei pointed out in the comments, this is the correct understanding for a `bool` *filter*:

- `must` can be translated as `(A and B)`
- `should` can be translated as `(C or D)`
- `must_not` can be translated as `((not E) and (not F))`

Each one of them is an operation that stands alone, but they can be combined exactly as you have shown.

```
(A and B) and (C or D) and ((not E) and (not F))
```

Speaking in terms of boolean logic, the reason that it's not the same thing as `(not (E and F))` is because that is the same as saying `((not E) or (not F))`. If `E` is the same as saying `field == 5` and `F` is the same as saying `field == 6`, then that is the same as `field != 5 or field != 6`, which is always going to be true!

This leads to looking at it a different way:

- `must_not` can be translated as `(not (E or F))`

In other words, the document does not match if any filter does not match. This leads to a slightly simplified version of the combined version:

```
(A and B) and (C or D) and (not (E or F))
```

Comment: pickypg, thanks for the crystal-clear and expanded explanation! Regards.

Comment: A lot better than my simple "yes" haha.