# ElasticSearch Query with two fields and 'AND' filter - Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, java

Let's say I have a index in elasticsearch with two fields: `title` and `tags`. I have few documents there

1. Should be returned by query

   ```
   { title: "My main title on this page", tags: ["first", "whatever"] }
   ```
2. Should not be returned by query

   ```
   { title: "My on this page", tags: ["first", "page", "whatever"] }
   ```
3. Should be returned by query

   ```
   { title: "My main title on this page", tags: ["page", "whatever"]}
   ```

I want to find all documents which title `CONTAINS` "main title" `AND` tag "first" `OR` "page".
I want to use `java API` for this, but I'm not sure how can I do this. I know that I can use filter query to create "`or`" and "`and`". Not sure how can I add to query the title part, and how can I get the logic with "at least one from the list".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you care about the order of the "main" and "title" words (is it a phrase), but this is relatively simple:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : "main title"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms" : {
            "tags" : [ "first", "page" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

By default, the `terms` query is going to work as a single match and it will boost the score (relevancy) by matching multiple tags. This will perform an *exact* match, which you should *only* do with `not_analyzed` strings. Anything with in the `must` will inherently behave like an `AND`; you can understand the [bool query/filter by checking here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29909272/706724). This translates pretty simply into the Java API:

```
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

SearchResponse response =
    client.prepareSearch("your-index").setTypes("your-type")
          .setQuery(
               boolQuery()
                   .must(matchPhraseQuery("title", "main title"))
                   .must(termsQuery("tags", "first", "page"))
          .execute()
          .actionGet();
```